# css display table layout breaks when adding a img tag

Tags: css

I have a problem with css regarding display table and img tag. Here is the jsfindle link that ilustrate the issue:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpruizmdq/m6Uya/1/)

the code simplified:

```
<section>
<article class="image">
    <img src="http://www.locostusa.com/forums/download/file.php?avatar=16004_1381633145.jpg"/>
</article>
<article>
    <span>.....</span>
</article>
</section>
```

I have a section tab with display: table and two article tags inside with display:table-cell. inside the first article tag i have an img tag, on the second one i have only an span with text.

The issue is that the text is rendered with a huge space above almost the size of the image. What can i do to get rid of the space?

Comment: is there a specific reason you are using `display:table` your layout could be easily done with more apropriate techniques line `display:inline-block` or `float:left`

Comment: i'm not an expert on css. but i wanted a layout similar to a table. Maybe i can try with this option too. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to the `article` element since you changed the display to `table-cell`. The default value of the `vertical-align` property is `baseline`; thus the text is aligned to the bottom.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZXXw/)

```
article {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

It's worth noting that values such as `middle` and `bottom` will work too. You basically just need to change it from the default.

Comment: Ah, you got me. So I'll just repeat what I added in my answer: "Otherwise, the article text's first line's baseline is aligned to the baseline of the image."

Comment: Thanks for you help! It works! I will accept your answer in a few minutes!

Comment: OP: also you may or may not want to use the *other* table layout algorithm, the one triggered by `table-layout: fixed` (on the parent element displayed as table) that will adapt widths to exactly what you want instead of trying to adapt to content (both are fine and have their use cases depending on the situation)